# Can there be a difference on how a web application looks when it is accessed via IP Address and when via the host name of the machine?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, tomcat

This might sound a little bizarre, it sounded to me, when I received a question that one of our applications looks different when it is accessed in IE 11 via hostname and when via its IP address.

So what happens is, in IE 11 the alignment of the items is distorted when it is viewed by the hostname and looks correct when it is accessed via Ip address.

The app is deployed on a tomcat container, running on springs and hibernate.

Is it even possible, has anyone ever seen this behaviour or the user might have messed something up. I tried to do the same in the app but couldn't reproduce it, however when I switched on the "compatibility view" in IE the view is distorted.

Comment: Try to add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />  in your page. It may solve your issue

Comment: @MayankPandya It has been a while since you commented, I saw into your proposal and it looks like it might be helpful but what I am really concerned about is "why" this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a webapp that looks different depending on if you use hostname or IP address, but it's not something that would happen easily unless you attempt to do it.

I suspect that the problem lies with IE. Does it work properly on Firefox, Chrome and Safari?

Comment: I can't be sure about it, as I didn't see the behaviour but was reported to me by one of the users. But sure it looks like a good start to investigate it.

Comment: as you mentioned that this can be programmed, can you please provide a link in which I can look into this, I would really want to know more about it.

Comment: @chetanmelkani It's not really about programming, it's about server configurations that can mess up things such as paths. However this doesn't sound like it's a configuration error, since it would be easily reproduced.